# Select chosen is not working in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've been populating my drop down list by using ng-repeat directives but when i tried to use multiple select option using select chosen class (jquery) then its showing nothing more than the expressions itself.

```
<select id="trainer"  size="1" name="trainer"  class="form-control" ng-model="user.cont_id" multiple>
   <option value="">Select trainer</option>
   <option ng-repeat="trainer in trainers track by $index" value="{{trainer.id}}">{{trainer.fname}}&nbsp;{{trainer.lname}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Angular-Chosen for multiple select options. It is an angular directive that can be used to convert select boxes to a more user-friendly chosen drop downs.

You can follow this [link](http://adityasharat.github.io/angular-chosen/) and go to Multiple Select sections to see how it works.

Might be useful for you.

Comment: it worked....but in case if i dont want to use any library , what would be the alternate method you would like to provide to cater the problem.?

Answer (score 0):

according to the doc the correct way to iterate over options is using `ng-options` directive

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="trainer as trainer.fname for trainer in trainers ">
</select>
```